# Why doesn't an NSIndexPath second value equal the indexPath.row?

Tags: ios

Inspecting an `NSIndexPath`, why isn't the indexPath‘s second value equal to the indexPath.row?

[image: breakpoint]

Observing an instance of `NSIndexPath` at a breakpoint, and comparing the variable `indexPath`, the second value is 192 in the **Variables View**, while `po indexPath.row` value is 11 in the **Console**.

What causes this discrepancy?

Comment: post some code or else elaborate clearly.

Comment: Show picture, fix typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, you should probably use `IndexPath`, which will bridge over to Objective-C API to the `NSIndexPath` class. ([Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsindexpath))

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the IndexPath structure, which bridges to the NSIndexPath class. The IndexPath value type offers the same functionality as the NSIndexPath reference type, and the two can be used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C APIs. This behavior is similar to how Swift bridges standard string, numeric, and collection types to their corresponding Foundation classes.

While not an answer, using `IndexPath` instead of `NSIndexPath` does not exhibit the misleading behavior.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 11, section: 0)
```

`po indexPath.row` yields `11`, as does the **Variables View** (see the `_indexes` structure below):

[image: Variables view]